# Check if a set of radio buttons are checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to count the amount of radio buttons checked out of 12 questions, but it returns 0 each time, but I think I set it up correctly so I'm not sure where the problem is. Went it over again and again.

The JavaScript code trying to count the answers in the 1st set of questions

```
const set1a = set1.children;
const set1 = document.getElementById('set1');
const nextB1 = document.getElementById('next1');

function n1() {
var setac = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < set1a[i].length; i++) {
    const set1ch = set1a[i].children

    for (let j = 0; j < set1ch[2].length; j++) {
        const set1che = set1ch[2].children
        for (let k = 0; k < set1che.length; k++) {
            if (set1che[k].querySelector('input:checked')) {
                setac++;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (setac == 12) {
    nextB1.addEventListener('click', next1)
    function next1() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        set1.classList.add('hide')
        set2.classList.remove('hide')
    }
}
else {
    alert('Kérem mindenhol adjon meg egy választ!')
}
console.log(setac)
}
```

The overcomplicated HTML code, which I need like this ( it has 12 of these like A1. A2. ...etc)

```
<div class="" id="set1">
            <div>
                <h3>A1.</h3>
                <div class="question"><img src="img/a1/10.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="ans ans-grid-6">
                    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="1"><img src="img/a1/11.png" alt="">
                    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="2"><img src="img/a1/12.png" alt="">
                    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="3"><img src="img/a1/13.png" alt="">
                    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="4"><img src="img/a1/14.png" alt="">
                    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="5"><img src="img/a1/15.png" alt="">
                    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="6"><img src="img/a1/16.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Button checking if the user can advance to the next set of questions

```
<div class="controls">
      <button id="next1" class="next-btn btn" 
          onclick="n1()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out, sorry for the bother

```
function n1() {
var setac = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < set1a.length; i++) {
    const set1ch = set1a[i].children;
    for (let j = 0; j < set1ch.length; j++) {
        
        if (set1ch[j].querySelector('input:checked')) {
            setac++;
        }
    }
    
}

if (setac === 12) {
    nextB1.addEventListener('click', next1)
    function next1() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        set1.classList.add('hide')
        set2.classList.remove('hide')
    }
}
else {
    alert('Kérem mindenhol adjon meg egy választ!')
}
console.log(setac)
```

}